# C# Bitmap "following" Transparent Form

Tags: c#, forms, system.drawing

I have a transparent form by using

```
this.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Wheat;
this.TopMost = true;
```

and I want to create a Bitmap so I can use Bitmap.GetPixel, but I want the GetPixel coordinates to "follow" where the form is located in the screen, 
e.g: I set `Bitmap bitmap = new bitmap(this.width,this.height)` and then I do `Bitmap.GetPixel(400,400)` it would get the pixel information in the coordinates 400,400 inside the Bitmap right? Well but I want it to "follow" the form as I move it around I want the Bitmap to follow the form around. Is that possible?
If you didn't understand ***I want the bitmap to follow my form around***

Comment: So if the form is at 0, 0 on the screen and say that corresponds to 400, 400 on the bitmap, then the user moves the form to 100, 200 on the screen that would correspond to 500, 600 on the Bitmap?

Comment: Is the bitmap displayed in your form?

Comment: Yes and No actually

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if you meant the following:

```
int initial_x = 400, initial_y = 400;
Color color = Colors.Transparent;

if (this.Top >= 0 && this.Top < initial_x && this.Left >= 0 && this.Left < initial_y)
    color = Bitmap.GetPixel(initial_x - this.Top, initial_y - this.Left);
```